# showAnnotToolsWhenNoCollab and Acrobat 9

Tags: acrobat, collaboration

This code

```
js_obj := oAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject;
js_obj.Collab.showAnnotToolsWhenNoCollab := true;
```

which used to work in Acrobat 7 and 8 (and was infact required to enabled editing of note/annotations/comments) appears to crash Acrobat 9.

Does anyone know if there is a work around (the one listed [here](http://www.adobeforums.com/webx/.59b7bcf3) does not work for me).  Anyone from Adobe use SO and care to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [you're not the only one](http://www.adobeforums.com/webx/.59b7bcf3) with this problem. It has been reported to Adobe as a known bug.

Comment: just realized the link you have is the one I found. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the interest though :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug.

It seems to have been fixed in update 9.1